# can I print from phonegap's inappbrowser

Tags: printing, cordova, inappbrowser

Can i print from Phonegap's inappbrowser in iOS  ??
because from SAFARI there is print button but not in the inappbrowser. 
if can't is there any solution to print from phonegap apps. ?
why i use inappbrowser instead external browser (safari) because my URL is in local directory.
and safari cannot open local files, but inappbrowser can.